# Delete post without loading page - symfony4

Tags: php, jquery, doctrine, symfony4

I am new to Symfony. I want to delete my post using the jquery DELETE method. I have jquery code delete my post when I click on the delete button it reloads the page after confirmation but didn't delete my post. Please check my code and fix the problems.

I copied code from https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WVeE4SXIOwA

This is the delete button in **twig**

```
<button class="delete-btn" data-id="{{ post.id }}" style="font-size:15px; color:red;">
Delete
</button>
```

**post.js**

```
const articles = document.getElementById('post');

if(articles) {
    articles.addEventListener('click', e => {
        if (e.target.className === 'delete-btn' ) 
        {
          if(confirm('Are you sure?')) {
              const id = e.target.getAttribute('data-id');

              fetch(`/post/delete/${id}`, {
                  method: 'DELETE'
              }).then(res => window.location.reload());
          }
        }
    });
}
```

**Controller**

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use App\Entity\Post;
use App\Entity\User;
use App\Entity\Rating;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Method;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;


class PostController extends AbstractController
{
   /**
    * @Route("post/delete/{id}")
    * @Method({"DELETE"})
    */
     public function delete(Request $request, $id)
     {

        $post = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Post::class)->find($id);

        $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $entityManager->remove($post);
        $entityManager->flush();

        $response = new Response();
        $response->send();
      }
}
```

When I click the button it confirms by alert "Are you sure?" after clicking ok and then it doesn't delete my post. Please help me to find the solution

Answer (score 0):

You should be using `window.location.reload(true)` in order to reload the page from the server (with updated data). By default the browser reloads from the cache (where the entity still existed). See here for details: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/reload#Syntax

Comment: thanks to giving an answer, now it's working without changes.